# Reading out MySQL table and echo out 2 records with a different status in 1 div

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using a MySQL table called Articels.
In this table there are records and they all have a STATUS.
There are 2 kinds of status: FOR SALE AND SOLD

Now I would like to use one div that shows 1 record with status SOLD and one div with status FOR SALE.
These are contained in a div (see example below)

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM Articles WHERE status = 'FOR SALE' OR status = 'SOLD'";

...

while($raw_results > 0){ ?>

<div>
<div>IF status = 'SOLD'</div>     //DIV with 1 record SOLD
<div>IF status = 'FOR SALE'</div> //DIV with 1 record FOR SALE

</div>

} ?> //end of while loop
```

I could use a left column (DIV) with all records 'SOLD' and a right column with all records 'FOR SALE' but this makes the page load awfully bad. First the left then the right. This isn't the solution, because I am using 'ypos' when the page is refreshed.

Anybody an idea to solve this?

Thx,

Manu

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking for. So you want a `div` where it has SOLD articles and a `div` where it has FOR SALE articles? Just run two different querys and populate the `div`s respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Why wouldn't you consider getting your data in two separate arrays? One for SOLD and one for FOR SALE. Run two queries instead. Simply try avoiding situations you may not be able to handle.